# Using dompdf with absolute links

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am using the standard DOMPDF code to render existing web pages (e.g.[1](http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/16/2/1.html)):

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_base_path($artpath);
$dompdf->load_html_file($artpath);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($pdfpath);
```

where `$artpath`' is the path to the HTML code and `$pdfpath` is the name of the PDF.

However, the web page contains both relative links (which are correctly followed) and absolute links (e.g. `/gifs/bullet.gif`) which are not found.  This is probably because the DOMPDF code is being executed at http://www.epress.ac.uk/src/xtra/makeapdf.php, `www.epress.ac.uk` being a virtual domain on my server, which also hosts the virtual domain `jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk` (that is, both domains are on the **same** server).  It would seem that DOMPDF is using the document root of `www.epress.ac.uk`, when it should be using the document root of `jasss.surrey.ac.uk`.

Is there some way around this?  I have tried resetting `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to the document root of `jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk` before calling `new DOMPDF()`, but this doesn't seem to solve the problem.  I get errors such as:

```
file_get_contents(/styles/jasssarticle.css) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Unable to load css file /styles/jasssarticle.css
```

The web page is valid HTML according to the www validator.w3.org

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: What is the value of the `$artpath` variable? When you call `$dompdf->load_html_file()` with a relative path dompdf sets the root path to the file system root, not the website document root.

Comment: `$artpath` is `/Volumes/Documents/VirtualSites/jasss/16/2/1.html'.  The webroot of jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk is `/Volumes/Documents/VirtualSites/jasss/`.  Hope that helps... Thanks.

Comment: Also forgot to ask, what version of dompdf?

Comment: The latest - downloaded a couple of days ago - but I can't be more specific because I can't find it referenced anywhere in the code I downloaded!

Answer (score 4):

You're loading a file via the file system. That means all references to external files that don't include a domain part in the path are rendered relative to the file system. You can reference files in three ways:

- Full URL (including domain), e.g. `http://example.com/image.png`. These are always read from the URL specified.
- Absolute path, e.g. `/file/path/image.png`. This is read relative to the root of the *file system*, not the root of the web site, or the user's home directory (in the case of shared hosting).
- Relative path (no leading slash), e.g. `file/path/image.png`. This is read relative to the HTML file. So in your case the file would be read from `/Volumes/Documents/VirtualSites/jasss/16/2/file/path/image.png`.

Calling `$dompdf->set_base_path()` only affects the relative path.

You'll have to modify the absolute file references to include the path to the website root, e.g. `/Volumes/Documents/VirtualSites/jasss/styles/jasssarticle.css`, or load the file via the website, e.g. `http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/16/2/1.html`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Indeed, using the URL seems to be the way forward, i.e `$dompdf->load_html_file("http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/16/2/2.html");`.  However, the results are rather disappointing:  the resulting PDF file stops short after about 7 pages and the images are all over the place. The same occurs with other similar pages (e.g. `.../16/2/1.html`) If you have dompdf running, you could see what you get with this URL (it is publicly available).  I displayed the contents of `$_dompdf_warnings` but this did not reveal anything much wrong (just a couple of invalid CSS properties).

Comment: The document does seem to be giving dompdf some trouble. I suspect a lot of the problems are because dompdf is confused about the document structure. I'll take a closer look when I get a chance.

Comment: "I'll take a closer look when I get a chance."  Have you had a chance? Thanks.

Comment: I always believed absolute file paths were a bit hackish. Thanks for your answer. `$dompdf->set_base_path()` and relative links (no leading slash) work great!