# Including style sheets in a PDF in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, dompdf

I am using `dompdf` to generate PDFs for some of the views and that is working just fine. The problem is that I cannot include the css files anywhere, and only css included in the `<style>` tags inside the view itself is taken into consideration.

Here is the controller action:

```
public function view_pdf($id=null){

    ini_set('memory_limit','512M');

    $event = $this->Event->findById($id);

        $evt_data=new \DateTime($event['Event']['date']);
        $this->set('event', $event);
        $this->layout='event';
}
```

Here is the layout:

```
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'dompdf' . DS . 'dompdf_config.inc.php');
spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper = 'A4';
$dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($content_for_layout), Configure::read('App.encoding'));
$dompdf->render();
echo $dompdf->stream('Event.pdf');
```

And here is the view itself (shortened version):

```
<style>
div.content-event{
    background: gray;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
<div class="content-event" style="margin-bottom: 80px">
<div class="heading">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3><?php echo $event['Event']['name']; ?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to include the css files in the usual way, like: `echo $this->Html->css('event');`, in both the view and the layout, but this is just not taking any action.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archana's answer appears to be valid, but I wanted to provide a bit more context. When you load a document using `$dompdf->load_html()` dompdf has no information about the source of the file. When you provide links to external resources dompdf sets the currently executing file *on the local file system* as the base path.

Essentially URLs will be parsed in the following manner:

- relative URLs (e.g. `css/styles.css`) will be evaluated relative to the currently executing file
- absolute URLs (e.g. `/css/styles.css`) will be evaluated relative to the file system root
- URLs with a domain (e.g. `http://example.com/css/styles.css`) will be evaluated as written

When you make the following call to [HTMLHelper::css](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::css):

```
$this->Html->css('styles')
```

CakePHP will produce a style reference similar to the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" />
```

Based on the parsing rules I outlined above that reference will be read from the filesystem root. And unless you have a root folder called "css" with your stylesheet in it that reference will be invalid. The reason Archana's answer works is that you're providing a path from the root of the file system to the file (e.g. `/inet/www/cakesite/app/webroot/css/styles.css`).

It's a bit easier to get a handle on external resource references if you specify a domain. In that manner dompdf will access the resource via your web server as would any web browser. This type of reference does require a bit more attention to your dompdf and server configuration.

You might find the following questions helpful on how to construct a URL:

- [Q: How to get the base Url in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13738711/264628)
- [Q: base_url in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4298552/264628)

Answer (score 2):

You can include CSS file like following:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo APP.'webroot'.DS.'css'.DS.'event.css'; ?>" media="all" />
```

Put your css file into webroot/css folder.

Comment: which file should I include it in?

Comment: Just did that, and now I am getting the following error: `Call to a member function prepend_child() on a non-object`
Any idea why?

Comment: I am not aware about this error. I used above code in my dompdf code and its working.

Comment: @Domas I believe this answer solved your problem. The issue you're encountering now is related to parsing of the HTML/CSS. I recommend you mark the answer and start a new question.